# Remove focus rect on control - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Is there any option to not draw "focus rect" on a control in Delphi 2009?

-Pavan.

Comment: Which control?  Relevant details make for better answers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for this varies depending on the inheritance of the control.  Some require an override of the Paint method, others require an ownerdraw.  I don't know of a general solution.

For some [Raize components](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/RzComps/) there is a `ShowFocusRect` property that you can set to false - one of the benefits of well-made components.

Some would say that what you propose is not a good idea - arguing that the focus rectangle is part of the standard Windows user interface (you will find a relevant discussion [here](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=16613)).  I'm sure there's a case to be made for overriding the behavior in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for suppressing the focus rectangle in a StringGrid using ownerdraw, from [this newsgroup post](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.language.objectpascal/browse%5Fthread/thread/33978836e82b85e2/cd3f9be60110a953?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=focus+rectangle+delphi+group:borland.public.delphi.language.objectpascal#cd3f9be60110a953).  This will not work for controls for which the focus rectangle is drawn in the Paint method.

Set default drawing to false, attach this to the OnDrawCell event:

```
procedure TMiscForm.StringGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject;
          ACol, ARow: Integer;
          Rect  : TRect;
          State : TGridDrawState);
var 
  SG: TStringGrid;
begin
  if Sender is TStringGrid then 
  begin
    SG:= TStringGrid(Sender);
    SG.Canvas.Font:= SG.Font;
    SG.Canvas.Brush.Color:= SG.Color;
    SG.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;

    if gdFixed in State then 
      SG.Canvas.Brush.Color:= SG.FixedColor;

    if  (gdSelected in State) and not (gdFocused  in State) then 
    begin
      SG.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clHighLight;
      SG.Canvas.Font.color := clHighLightText;
    end;

    SG.Canvas.Pen.Color  := SG.Canvas.Brush.Color;
    SG.Canvas.Pen.Mode   := pmCopy;
    SG.Canvas.Pen.Style  := psSolid;
    SG.Canvas.Pen.Width  := 1;
    SG.Canvas.Rectangle(Rect);

    if SG.Canvas.Ctl3D and (gdFixed in State) then 
    begin
      if goFixedVertLine in SG.Options then 
      begin
        SG.Canvas.Pen.Color  := clBtnHighLight;
        MoveTo(Rect.Left,  Rect.Bottom-1);
        LineTo(Rect.Left,  Rect.Top);
        SG.Canvas.Pen.Color  := clBtnShadow;
        MoveTo(Rect.Right-1,  Rect.Top);
        if goFixedHorzLine in SG.Options then 
          LineTo(Rect.Right-1, Rect.Bottom)
        else LineTo(Rect.Right-1, Rect.Bottom+SG.GridLineWidth);
      end;

      if goFixedHorzLine in SG.Options then 
      begin
        SG.Canvas.Pen.Color  := clBtnHighLight;
        MoveTo(Rect.Left,  Rect.Top);
        LineTo(Rect.Right, Rect.Top);
        SG.Canvas.Pen.Color  := clBtnShadow;
        if goFixedVertLine in SG.Options then 
        begin
          MoveTo(Rect.Left+1, Rect.Bottom-1);
          LineTo(Rect.Right,  Rect.Bottom-1)
        end 
        else 
        begin
          MoveTo(Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom-1);
          LineTo(Rect.Right + SG.GridLineWidth, Rect.Bottom-1);
        end;
      end;
    end;

    SG.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsClear;
    TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, SG.Cells[ACol,ARow]);

    SG.Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
    if gdFocused in State then 
      SG.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if your still interested you can always try

```
procedure TfrmPic.MyStringGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject;
  ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  // Deliberately draw focus rectangle which is subsequently redrawn;
  if gdSelected in State then 
    MyStringGrid.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end; { procedure TfrmPic.sgCorDrawCell }
```

Comment: Will this work generally? The OP did not specify inheritance of the object in question.